# Unable to refresh powerpivot data in sharepoint

Tags: excel, sharepoint, ssas, cube, powerpivot

I have a SSAS cube and I would like to create some reports using excel out of the data. Since creating a report directly from the cube involved some performance issues, I loaded the data from the cube into Power pivot and then created reports on top of the power pivot data.

Now, when I upload my excel report to power pivot gallery of sharepoint 2013, I am not able to refresh the data manually as well as automatically (via a schedule). I get the error:

**"An error occurred while working on the Data Model in the workbook. Please try again. 
We were unable to refresh one or more data connections in this workbook. 
The following connections failed to refresh"**

When scheduling the report, I get the error:

**"Call to Excel Services returned an error"**

Can any one help me to solve this issue please!

Thanks in advance

Comment: What were your performance issues running a report against the cube directly? Is the SSAS instance Multidimensional or Tabular? It's not unlikely you're running into security issues on SharePoint. Can you contact whoever configured that server?

Comment: Hi @greggyb, The report took more than 30 seconds for each filter, which really was not acceptable to the client. Hence, I had to use power pivot to pull data into the excel. The SSAS instance is tabular. I have contacted the sharepoint team to get more info about the security settings.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set up credentials in the Secure Store? Make sure you have set SERVER\POWERPIVOT in Manage Service Applications -> Excel Services Application - Data Model Settings.

Also, check ULS logs and post what you might find there.

Comment: Hi @vegardei, I have not set up SSS in the sharepoint. I need to check with the sharepoint team to implement it and will update if it works.